# Agent sql server in SSAS server

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssas, agent

Hi everyone I'm reading a tutorial in which they indicate to Configure SQL Agent to start automatically in SSAS server but I don't find itin services.
My question is should I install it or normally it's not installed in SSAS SERVER ?

Answer (score 0):

SQL Agent is only installed as part of the SQL Server Database Engine.  SSAS can be installed independently of the database engine.  SQL Server Configuration Manager will list all of the services installed.